# I deleted my Google+ and cannot access nor recover my SO account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email, account-recovery

I deleted my Google+ account so I can't anymore login to my SO account as usual.
When I'm trying to use my Gmail address to recover my old SO account, it gives me a new one.
I tried to log in with Facebook and SE account, but both are giving me a new account.

I've got only my e-mail address that Google+ was based on, and found my old StackOverflow profile page. That's all I have. What can I do to get my old account back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the **[Contact Us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)** link at the footer of every page is the best way to help you. You need help from the Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: I sent them my issue via "Contact Us" and a day already passed, but they didn't respond at all. Do you have any guess how much time usually it takes them? I am afraid they won't answer at all just as with many other sites.

Comment: @user256163 It's the weekend in the US (and I presume wherever you are). Wait until Monday :)

Comment: @user256163 I responded to your ticket, but as Michael pointed out, it's the weekend so things are a fair bit slower around here than they are during the week. I'll try to check back later for your response, but if all else fails, you should hear back again tomorrow.

Comment: Problem solved. got my old account back.